# Application - voice recorder run once then crashes - how to set up try&catch

Tags: java, android

I have this application that records the users voice and then play it. My problem is that the app works fine the first cycle, I can record, stop recording and play the sound. When I then click record for the second time the application crashes. I use the permissions "Write external storage" and "Record Audio" in the manifest file. If someone knows what is wrong, please help me out!

```
package com.example.t.voicerecorder;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.LocalTime;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button playBtn;
private Button stopBtn;
private Button startBtn;
private String outputFile;
private MediaRecorder recorder;
MediaPlayer player=null;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    playBtn=findViewById(R.id.ButtonPlay);
    startBtn=findViewById(R.id.ButtonStart);
    stopBtn=findViewById(R.id.ButtonStop);
    stopBtn.setEnabled(false);
    playBtn.setEnabled(false);

    outputFile= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/recording.3gp";

    recorder=new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);
}

public void StartRecording(View view) {

    try {
        recorder.prepare();
        recorder.start();
    } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {

    } catch (IOException iox) {

    }
    startBtn.setEnabled(false);
    playBtn.setEnabled(false);
    stopBtn.setEnabled(true);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recording has started",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public void StopRecording(View view){

    recorder.stop();
    recorder.release();
    recorder=null;
    stopBtn.setEnabled(false);
    playBtn.setEnabled(true);
    startBtn.setEnabled(true);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recording has stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public void PlayRecording(View view){

     player=new MediaPlayer();

    try{
        player.setDataSource(outputFile);
        player.prepare();
        player.start();

        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Playing last recording", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    catch (Exception ex){

    }
}}
```

Comment: catch (Exception ex){

    } ... or in other words, happy debugging, dude

Comment: _"the application crashes"_ Then you should add the stacktrace to your question.

Comment: @Michael he doesn't have any, he's hiding all his Exceptions

Comment: @Stultuske: There should be a stacktrace in the logs caused by the uncaught exception.

Comment: @Michael who says it's uncaught?

Comment: @Stultuske: OP says the app _crashes_. A likely reason is that he has an uncaught exception. In any case, OP needs to provide more info about the problem. Just saying that _"the application crashes"_ isn't helpful.

Comment: yes, brilliant. but does he know it crashes because a stacktrace, or because it "stops working"?